# Present moment awareness

Tags: personal-practice, theravada

What is the different between living in present and the mindfulness? I experience living in the present without thinking but often not with mindfulness.

Answer (score 1):

In the Satipaṭṭhāna Sutta, the Buddha teaches how a practitioner should dwell with (right) mindfulness of body and mind;

> (The Four Postures)
>
> 6. “Again, bhikkhus, when walking, a bhikkhu understands: ‘I
>      am walking’; when standing, he understands: ‘I am standing’;
>      when sitting, he understands: ‘I am sitting’; when lying
>      down, he understands: ‘I am lying down’; or he understands
>      accordingly however his body is disposed.
>
> -- *MN 9: Satipaṭṭhāna Sutta, p. 146 - (Bodhi, Trans.)*

and

> (Contemplation of Mind)
>
> 34. “And how, bhikkhus, does a bhikkhu abide contemplating
>       mind as mind? Here a bhikkhu understands mind affected
>       by lust as mind affected by lust, and mind unaffected by lust as
>       mind unaffected by lust. He understands mind affected by hate
>       as mind affected by hate, and mind unaffected by hate as mind
>       unaffected by hate. He understands mind affected by delusion
>       as mind affected by delusion, and mind unaffected by delusion
>       as mind unaffected by delusion. He understands contracted
>       mind as contracted mind, and distracted mind as distracted
>       mind. He understands exalted mind as exalted mind, and unexalted
>       mind as unexalted mind. He understands surpassed mind
>       as surpassed mind, and unsurpassed mind as unsurpassed
>       mind. He understands concentrated mind as concentrated
>       mind, and unconcentrated mind as unconcentrated mind. He
>       understands liberated mind as liberated mind, and unliberated
>       mind as unliberated mind.
>
> -- *MN 9: Satipaṭṭhāna Sutta, p. 150 - (Bodhi, Trans.)*

It is taught that one should be mindful of whatever phenomena arises in the body and mind.

Insight-meditationally speaking this means that one should take whatever physical or mental object that arises and cultivate insight from it. If a feeling of anger arises, one takes that feeling as an object. If aversion towards that feeling of anger arises, one takes the aversion as an object and so forth.

One practices to realize the [*Three Characteristics of Existence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_marks_of_existence); "impermanence, unsatisfactoriness and uncontrollability". All conditioned phenomena are subject to these three characteristics. They are also the 3 gateways to Liberation as taught in the [*Visuddhimagga*](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf);

> [The Triple Gateway To Liberation]
>
> It enters upon the state of the triple gateway to liberation now with the
>   predominance of [one of] three faculties according as the contemplation occurs
>   in [one of] the three ways.
>   For it is the three contemplations that are called the three gateways to liberation, according as it is said: “But these three gateways to liberation lead to the outlet from the world, [that is to say,]
>
> (i) to the seeing of all formations as limited and circumscribed
>   and to the entering of consciousness into the signless element,
>
> (ii) to the stirring up of the mind with respect to all formations and to the entering of consciousness into
>   the desireless element,
>
> (iii) to the seeing of all things (dhamma) as alien and to the
>   entering of consciousness into the voidness element. These three gateways to
>   liberation lead to the outlet from the world”.
>
> -- *Visuddhimagga: The Path of Purification, p. 685-88, by Ven. Buddhaghosa*

Answer (score 0):

Living in present is the phrase used by Buddhists to refer to mindfulness. Mindfulness can be something like "When we walk, we walk. When we eat, we eat." Mindfulness can also be non distraction, being here.